# JsonPath could not be found for FlowFile - SplitJson Processor - Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

SplitJson processor is throwing warning message when the json path does not exists. We wants to ignore this messages on our prod environment.

*Example:*
{"Payload":{"ProfileScores":{"scoreList":[{"Profile":"Value 1","MatchedPatternId":"Value 2"}]}}}

Now based on above json, if we use the SplitJson processor with **$.Payload.ProfileScores.scoreList[*]** as JsonPath Expression then **everything works fine** because the path is accessible.

BUT
 in some cases **ProfileScores object is null** like this: {"Payload":{"ProfileScores":""}}.

Now as ProfileScores object is empty or null, then SplitJson throws the warning message for that particular flowfile.
[image]

Now we want to remove those warning message as it is clogging up the logs area in prod environment.

Is there any way to check if $.Payload.ProfileScores is null/empty or exists or not before sending the flowfile to SplitJson processor?

Solutions i have tried:

1. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Apache-nifi-Split-json-error-when-an-array-has-only-one/td-p/236040
2. "Path not found behavior" is not available on SplitJson processor, so could not use that.

Comment: Use EvaluateJsonPath to check if value is empty

Answer (score 0):

here is an expression you could use:

```js
$.Payload[?(@.ProfileScores nin [null,''])].ProfileScores.scoreList[*]
```

`?(expression)` - where

`@` - current element

`A nin []` - A not in array on the right

more explanation and examples here: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples

---

i used your file from question and this jsonpath works fine in nifi 1.16.3

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, but can you please check the expression again? The EvaluateJsonPath processor is throwing "Space not allowed in the path" error

Comment: Also if i try to this expression : $..book.length() , the it throws the file in unmatched relationship.

Comment: if you have ProfileScores only null (or missing) value try this: `$.Payload[?(@.ProfileScores!=null])].ProfileScores.scoreList[*]`

Comment: `$..book` not working because you don't have item `book`. but you could try `$..scoreList`

Comment: I mean to say that i tried with $...scoreList.length() , but not getting any result... the flowfile gets into unmatched relationship

Comment: $.Payload[?(@.ProfileScores!=null])].ProfileScores.scoreList[*], throws an error "String index out of range: 25"

Comment: I used your file from question and jsonpath works well in nifi 1.16.3. Which version are you using?

Comment: I guess mine is 1.5 (i have checked in About option under right side menu)